# Merge a large number of array with objects in one single array with all objects

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I am fetching multiple arrays of objects for my application. As seen in the picture below the data I get from my backend is one single array containing multiple array of objects. But what I want is one single array containing ***all*** objects.

[image: Arrays of array of objects]

```
 //Array of array of objects
 backendData.forEach((data) => {
     //data
 });
```

I already tried using the spread syntax in the for each loop but without success.
I also found a method which takes a variable number of arrays with objects and return one single array of objects:

```
const merge = (...arrays: any[]) => {
    const merged = {};

    arrays.forEach((data) => data.forEach((o: { id: string }) => Object.assign((merged[o.id] ??= {}), o)));

    return Object.values(merged);
  };
```

This works when I use the method with static arrays, but I can´t seem to figure out how to convert my data to a single array containing all objects from the other arrays...

Comment: Try this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Answer (score 0):

```
const arrays = [[{..}], [{..}],[{..}],[{..}],[{..}].....];

const merged = [].concat.apply([], arrays);
```

if this not works but static value work for this, that mean browser is braking the data there is only a one array so, you don't have to merge it

for check your exact array
**GO TO >> developer tools >> networks >> click on your API >> response**

but i don't things it a good idea to load that much data there must be a server side pagination